# css/js/php rounded corners in row or html element

Tags: css, rounded-corners

There is supposed to be a way to create rounded corners in a table row or element using just a few lines of code.  (This seems preferable to other more complicated ways using images.)

```
#example1 {
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

However, as a css/js noob, I don't know what to do with this.  Can I put it in a style tag within the element to round? Do it put it in .css file? I don't want this to apply to all rows or table cells, just one.  Many thanks for the correct syntax/usage.

Comment: It is possible that the browser (or the specs) do not allow `tr` or `td` to have rounded borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a style attribute on your container :

```
<div style="-moz-border-radius: 15px; border-radius: 15px;">....</div>
```

or in your css file:

```
.class1 { 
    -moz-border-radius: 15px; 
    border-radius: 15px; 
}  

//and add it to your container:
<div class="class1">....</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible  this only works with td, and not with div, span or tr?  I put the class in a <style type="text/css"> tag in the header and then invoked inside the <td> tag and it worked so I am now good.  However, when I tried it in a tr,div or span, it did not work.   As a related question, my .css file does seem to be working.  I have it in <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">.  Could another.css link I put in for some javascript be interfering?

Comment: you can use as many <link> tags you want. the border-radius works with all BLOCK elements, so sometimes you need to give your element a width and height and `display: block` in your CSS

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, this is not IE 8 or bellow friendly, although in Chrome, Safari and Firefox (etc) it works.

If you're only going to be using this once, put it directly in your container.

```
<div style="-moz-border-radius: 15px; border-radius: 15px;"> Content here </div>
```

If you are going to be using this more then once on the page, I suggest putting it at the top of your page in the head (or in a stylesheet file):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .roundedcorners { 
        -moz-border-radius: 15px; 
        border-radius: 15px; 
    }  
</style>
```

and in the container putting

```
<div class="roundedcorners"> Content here </div>
```

Here's a useful website to help you with using it in tables: http://www.red-team-design.com/practical-css3-tables-with-rounded-corners